# View outlook calendar in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, outlook

I am building an intranet using Asp.net C#. Users are login using their windows login via Windows Authentication. My question is how I can show their available time and appointments in their calendar within a day range? It does not have to be fancy.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried to just use OWA inside of a panel or something?

Comment: How can you do that? Can you provide more info please.

Comment: You should ask directed question about code you are having trouble with.  Be sure to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am placing the OWA into an iframe and only looking at the calendar. If you take away &module=calendar then you will get all of outlook.

```
<iframe src="https://mail.webpage.org/owa?cmd=contents&module=calendar"; width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" style="border-radius: 20px;"> </iframe>
```

Comment: The page is not showing up in iframe. Saying "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" I am able to login webmail using the link in iframe.

Comment: are you using your owa web source?